Event Monitoring, Pub/Sub API Issues
My customer has acquired the Event Monitoring product, and I've been working hard to find the answer to this question. However, after all my research, I am still unclear.
Is there a way to capture (and process) Event Monitoring / Shield events in real time?

I've seen examples of subscribing to the new EventBus using Lightning components, but my use cases do not involve the User interface at all.
I've seen a lot of talk about subscribing to the new EventBus from external applications/languages but not from Apex or Flow.

There are a few Event Monitoring events (like apianomalyevent) that show up in my custom objects/events list in Salesforce now, but not ALL of them.
Is it possible?

Might not be understanding the question, but I think that is what Transaction Security Policy is for no? On policy x being triggered, send email\notification

If you'd like to subscribe to Event Monitoring events from within the Platform, there are two options:

you can use transaction security policy as @BritishBoyinDC mentioned in his comments. This is a no code simple approach.
you can build some flows or Apex triggers to subscribe to the standard Platform Events sent by Event Monitoring. This approach gives you more control but you'll have to test and maintain the custom logic that you implement. These standard events are consumed in the same way as any custom user-defined platform events.


You can subscribe to these standard events with my Streaming Monitor app to explore the data that they hold: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FYEEWUA5

Thanks, @POZ.  So are you saying that if Event Monitoring is set up correctly, and I have the right permissions assigned, I should see those objects in the list, if I build a PlatformEvent Flow?

Of the objects on that list, only about 5 of them show up as Platform Events in Flow builder and as objects in my Objects list.  They are API Anomaly, Credential Stuffing, Guest User Anomaly, Report Anomaly, and Session Hijacking.
Login, BulkAPI, and a bunch of others are missing.  Am I maybe missing something in configuration or is it half-implemented (at least in the UI)?

I wasn't aware of this but these event have various level of support and this is documented when you click on the events from the table in the doc page that I shared above.
For example, PermissionSetEvent supports the Pub/Sub API and the Streaming API (CometD) but it doesn't support triggers, flows and processes.
The general use case for Event Monitoring is transaction security policy and third party systems integrations so the basic support is Pub/Sub API and the Streaming API (CometD). Internal Platform consumption with Apex/Flow/Processes seems like less common use cases.
